# Java-Collection search

Tags: java, collections

I have a variable length Collection full of one letter strings (it can be any type of collection). I am trying to create a result based on what the collection contains. If all of the letters in the collection are "P" then the result is "P", if all of the letters are "N" then the result is "N", if there is a mix of the two then the result is "NC". Is there anyway to do this without creating a complicated mess of loops? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you show us any code of what you've tried?

Comment: This should work within just one loop... please share your code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you could use:

```
Collections.frequency(f, "N");
```

Just like this:

```
String n = "N";      
Collection f = new ArrayList();
f.add(n);
f.add(n);
f.add(n);
f.add(n);
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(f, n));
```

Comment: ... and then compare the result against the size of the collection.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you. I didnt know about this method.

Answer (score 0):

you could convert the collection to a set, then each element will only occur once, and you can just loop through the set to collect an single instance of each entry (ie, ever element that was in the collection will occur exactly once within the set).

I believe

`Set newSet = new HashSet(existingCollection)`

will work for that

Comment: since the hashset constructor is going to have to iterate the collection, it might be more efficient to just iterate the collection himself. that way he can apply short circuit logic and avoid unnecessary object creation.

Comment: possibly. But the built in function is probably reasonably well optimized, so there's a good chance that even with that he won't beat it. Also, unless this is a super performance critical component, the solution that works immediately is probably better than spending a while getting a marginally better homegrown one to work.